# minValue and maxValue as Time Range in hAxis in Google Chart

Tags: datetime, google-visualization

I need to set time range for my hAxis to have minValue of 09:00 and maxValue 17:00 with increment of 1 hour (i.e. 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, ... , 17)

Currently my data is formatted as H:m (for example: 09:35, 10:20)

```
var formatter3 = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'H:m'});
formatter3.format(data,0);
```

And below are my options:

```
var options = {           
            curveType: "function",
            title : '',           
            hAxis:{slantedTextAngle: 90,textStyle:{fontSize:8}},
            colors : ['red','#3366CC', '#999999'],
            vAxes: {
                0: {logScale: false, format:'0.0000'},
                1: {logScale: false}
            },
            hAxis: { 
                           format: 'H:m',
                           minValue: new Date(null, null, null, 9, 0, 0),
                           maxValue: new Date(null, null, null, 17, 0, 0),         
                           viewWindow:{min: new Date(null, null, null, 9, 0, 0),
                                       max: new Date(null, null, null, 17, 0, 0)},
            series: { 
                0: {targetAxisIndex:0, type: "line"},
                1: {targetAxisIndex:0, type: "line"},
                2: {targetAxisIndex:1, type: "bars"}
            }         
        };
```

However , it is still not working. Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: 9 years later, your code seems to work! I haven't tried exactly all of your options, but I just used myself the combination of `minValue` , `maxValue` and `viewWindow` and it works for me with Dates! `minValue` and `maxValue` are not sufficient, because they only seem to extend the axis, if the data doesn't yet fill the desired range, but they never truncate data. So `viewWindow` is necessary to truncate the view. I was missing the last and found it in your question. So thanks for that.

Comment: If for some reason it still doesn't work for somebody, one can of course also filter over the initial data for the truncation. In case you have it as array and the first column is the time as `Date`, it could be s.th. like  `data.filter(row=> row[0].valueOf() >= minMs && row[0].valueOf() <= maxMs)`. Similarly one could prepend or append an empty row with only minValue and maxValue as the Date entry in order to extend the view.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the minValue, maxValue, and baseline value are ignored for date and time values.  I am not sure that this is a recent bug but I just noticed it a week ago.  You might try to experiment with the viewWindow min and max, and the gridlines.count option to get the desired result.  Or you might be able to convert all your date values to strings, if the values are evenly spaced, in which case axes will use your explicit values.

Another new feature that could work for you is that you can provide an explicit array of tick values, with a ticks: [...] option.  In the current release of gviz, the formatting is done using your format option, and that should be enough for your needs.  In an upcoming release, you can also specify the formatting of each tick value.

So it might be best to specify the times in your example using timeofday values like so:

```
hAxis: {
  ticks: [[9, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0], [11, 0, 0], [12, 0, 0], ...]
}
```

I think you could do the same kind of thing with datetime values instead, if that's what your data values are.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Would you kindly provide some example of tick values to show how it can be done? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried the solutions above, but it doesn't work. Would you help to point me to the right direction? Thanks.
var options = {           
curveType: "function",           
hAxis:{slantedTextAngle: 90,textStyle:{fontSize:8}},
vAxes: {
 0: {logScale: false, format:'0.0000'},
 1: {logScale: false}
},
hAxis: {
 format: 'H:m',
 ticks: [[9, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0], [11, 0, 0], [12, 0, 0],[13, 0, 0],[14, 0, 0],[15, 0, 0],[16, 0, 0], [17, 0, 0]]
},
series: { 
 0: {targetAxisIndex:0, type: "line"},
 1: {targetAxisIndex:0, type: "line"},
 2: {targetAxisIndex:1, type: "bars"}
}         
};

Comment: You may need to use the latest version as well.  In your google.load() call, use "1.1" instead of "1".

Comment: Sorry, it still doesn't work:  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages: ["corechart"]});
 </script>